# Make sure pages are visited in order

Tags: php

How do make sure that, with my multi page form, users only visit in order, for example, there's a sort of landing page which users would be directed to if they went to any of the form page first. It would go from the landing page to the first form page through a button. It must be in PHP.

Comment: Just store a session variable which you can use as a flag to see what pages they have been to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need track user activity, for ex: if user completes step1 store $_SESSION['step'] = 2, then check if user tryes access some step if $_SESSION['step'] == currentStep then allow this step, else redirect to $_SESSION['step'].

Answer (score -1):

What about using a Step Counter.  This would be stored in a hidden variable in HTML, so you can post it.

```
if ($_POST['step_1']){
//Actions for Step 1
}
```

Comment: How would it be by-passed. My main target audience is predominantly kids so would it really be an issue?